# Orchard promoting from TEST to PROD

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have 3 environments currently:

1. DEV (with VS2012 and source code) - which connects to TEST db
2. TEST - which connects to TEST db
3. PROD - which connects to PROD db

The website is currently working fine on DEV and TEST (with Contents, Widgets, etc added already).

When I tried to promote to PROD, the website seems to work fine (all pages there, I can navigate, etc) - However, I cannot edit at all.

For example when adding new page/editing content I would get this error:

```
"An unhandled exception has occurred and the request was terminated. Please refresh the page. If the error persists, go back

could not insert: [Orchard.ContentManagement.Records.ContentItemVersionRecord][SQL:    INSERT INTO Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord (Number, Published, Latest, Data, ContentItemRecord_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()]

NHibernate.Exceptions.GenericADOException: could not insert: [Orchard.ContentManagement.Records.ContentItemVersionRecord][SQL: INSERT INTO Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord (Number, Published, Latest, Data, ContentItemRecord_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?); select SCOPE_IDENTITY()] ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'Orchard.dbo.Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails."
```

Also, when I tried to Disable Shape Tracing Module in PROD - it would say success, but then when I check it actually did not disable the module.

This is how I published it to PROD:

1. Build the project on DEV using build.cmd "compile;package"
2. Copy the content of build\Stage to PROD (the App_Data folder only has _marker.txt file)
3. Create a blank database in PROD
4. Open the website in PROD, which asks me to enter the site name, database details etc.
5. Now, when I open the website - it displays the default "TheThemeMachine" sites - which is fine
6. Then, I copy database from TEST to PROD (via SQL Server Export)
7. Now, when I open the website I got my website running fine, with all pages, etc but I got above Exception when trying to edit the content or add new pages

How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: Can you be more specific about step 6? Seems like you missed some crucial metadata, such as identity columns.

Comment: Rather than backup and restore database, I uses SQL Server Export Data (Within SQl Server - right click on database - All tasks - Export Data - then follow wizard by selecting all tables) to copy all tables  from TEST to PROD

Comment: Right, that probably didn't transfer identities, etc. Check your export parameters. You can also verify my hypothesis is correct by looking for identity columns on those tables. If I'm right, you don't have any.

Comment: Thanks Bertrand, yes I can confirm it's missing identity in PROD. Is that mean that my above steps are correct and will work as long as I ensure that in the Step 6 above I do backup and restore?

Comment: Backup and restore is safer, yes, although it's not the only way to do this. I'll copy this as an answer below, as this seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that your tables don't have the proper identities defined. You are probably also missing lots of metadata about the tables, due to the fact that you exported and imported without taking all the schema information. Backup/restore is a safer way to move the database around, although there are other ways, because you are guaranteed to have the same database, schema + data, on the other end.